# C# await seems not waiting

Tags: c#

I've created class for reusing thread. This class has one public method for queueing jobs.

```
public AwaitableJob<T> PrepareJob(Func<T> job)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            var aj = new AwaitableJob<T>(job);
            taskQueue.Enqueue(aj);
            System.Threading.Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
            return aj;
        }
    }
```

AwaitableJob is custom class which should provide awaiter object.

```
 public class AwaitableJob<T> : INotifyCompletion where T : class
{
    public Func<T> Job { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; } = false;
    private object result;

    public AwaitableJob(Func<T> job)
    {
        this.Job = job;
    }

    public AwaitableJob<T> GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        result = Job.Invoke();
        IsCompleted = true;
    }

    public object GetResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        continuation.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And I tried to use it this way

```
public async void Connect()
    {
        var atm = await Worker.PrepareJob(ConnectHelper) as PresentModel; 

        if (atm == null) return;
        var vm = new SwitchingViewModel(atm);
        vm.NavigateTo();
    }
```

But instead of waiting it always continues in execution so atm variable is always null. When I added breakpoints into AwaitableJob it showed that GetResult is called before IsCompleted was setted to true. Anyone knows where could be problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Reusing a Thread can have issues. Some settings are thread specific, so they would persist across jobs (Culture comes to mind). Are you sure you need to implement your own Thread Pooling? What speaks agaisnt the existing thread pooling approaches?

Comment: I'd strongly advise against creating your own awaitable objects.  There are *very* few situations in which that's appropriate, and this isn't one of them.  You should just be using `Task` any time you want to have an awaitable object.

Comment: This could be an issue from using `async void`.  `async void` is really only good for event handlers, not anything that you need to actually make sure awaits the full task.  Use `async Task` as your return type to return nothing but still be able to wait

Comment: @JamesFaix No, it's not a result of an `async void` method, it's a result of the incorrect implementation of an awaitable object in the code shown.

Comment: I don't understand your `INotifyCompletion` implementation. Your `OnCompleted()` method, which should just _register_ a completion callback, calls that callback immediately. So, naturally the framework thinks your awaitable has completed and doesn't wait. It's impossible to know for sure what's going on, since you didn't bother to provide a [mcve], and of course you probably shouldn't be implementing your own awaitable anyway. But if you really want an answer, you'll need to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
{
    continuation.Invoke();
}
```

The point of `OnCompleted` is to **register** a callback for when it *has* completed, but you are invoking the continuation *now*. The only time you should do that is for the thread-race condition where somebody checks `IsCompleted` and gets `false`, but the status **changes** between that and registering the callback. Other than that, what you should be doing is *storing* the callback, and invoking it from the code that *actually changes the status to completed* (which looks like your `Invoke` method), *again* remembering to consider thread-safety around the switchover.

Frankly, if this sounds complex: use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`

Comment: Thank you for correcting and explanation OnCompleted. Now it waits.